# Accessing indices in multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get the vector of the last dimension of the multidimensional array w with shape [7,11,4,4,4] using history as shown.

```
x = [4 for _ in range(3)]
y = [7,11]
z = x + y
w = np.ones(z)
history = [0,0]
last_dim = w[0,0,0,0]
last_dim = w[0,0,history]
```

Comment: can you add exactly what you want to get?

Comment: can you show us a "before" and "after"?

Comment: `w[0,0,0,0]` is equivalent to `w[(0,0,0,0)]`.  Or `idx = (0,0,0,0); w[idx]`.  Note `idx` is a tuple.  So you could construct it as `idx = (0,0)+tuple(history)`.  Or `idx = tuple([0,0]+history)`.  The key is that you want to pass a tuple as the indexing parameter.

Comment: Yes, I just solved it. Thank you so much!!!!